# Remove own website from google search

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I went to this site to get help last time to remove my results from google search including blocking new content from being displayed. Google admin tells me the `robots.txt` is blocking content but old content is still viable.

I contacted google by reporting my URL to get deleted but over a week of waiting, it is still there. Can I add any code to make it go away? It is very frustrating and I am becoming quite dismotivated to continue my work due to this problem.

My robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: In some legislations you have the right to require that your personal information is removed from search results. If one of such legislations applies to you, do ask. Otherwise wait for the results to go away.

Comment: While you wait, you can still return a 404 page to users coming from google (detect referer header). not the best solution, but better than nothing

Comment: Thank you guys. All the content is removed its just a front page now but the links are images are displayed in search with CACHED version .. that is the biggest issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you set the `robots.txt` like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Try to reindex your site via [Google's Webmaster Tools.](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and try [to Ask Google to crawl and index your URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)

Comment: What do you mean by reindex? I added a new request now to get the whole website removed since I made the previous rule before I had robots

Comment: if you tell to google about reindex your website, will "update" your site links for the search, if you have robots.txt all about your site will be removed , because you will not give access to the Google bot

Comment: thank you guys, this worked and everything from images to search links are removed! :) if I remove the robots.txt when I want to launch the site, does the old images/searches come up? or will it generate new?

Comment: Will generate new, be careful with your robots.txt, you don't need to remove it , just allow what you want. http://www.robotstxt.org/faq.html